# How to ignore(remove) <update handle="name" added in other layout

Tags: layout, magento2.2, update-handle

> module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml

has following code:

```
<update handle="sales_order_info_links"/>
```

**Is there any pretty way to remove such updates?**

p.s. I know about removing particular blocks existed in file `sales_order_info_links.xml` from another layout like this:

```
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links" remove="true" />
```

Comment: Hi, did anyone found out answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions to remove a `layout handle` from a layout file of a Magento module:

1. Remove all content within the `layout handle`, including blocks, containers, the `class` attribute, changing the title, etc. by using `referenceBlock`, `referenceContainer`, etc. in your layout XML file.
2. Remove the `layout handle` directly in the layout file using **the Composer patches plugin**.

In case the `layout handle` has many layout files (eg: the `customer_account` layout handle, which has several layout files) in several modules, solution 1 is difficult to implement and maintain. Therefore, solution 2 is recommended.

For instructions on how to create a custom composer patch, refer to the topic [How to create a Magento 2 Patch?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256571/create-magento-2-patch)

To apply a custom composer patch, I recommend using the [Vaimo Composer Patches plugin](https://github.com/vaimo/composer-patches).
You also can use the [Cweagans Composer Patches plugin](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches)

There is a Magento official document on how to apply a custom composer patch: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html

---

Regarding removing the `sales_order_info_links` layout handle from the `sales_order_view.xml` layout file of the Magento_Sales module. There is only one layout file, which is located in the Magento_Sales module with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" as="links" name="sales.order.info.links" before="-">
                ...
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Therefore, you can implement solution 1, which removes the layout handle content by declaring the following in your `sales_order_view.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.info.links" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Related topic: [How to change <update handle="customer_account"/> in wishlist layout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370148/how-to-change-update-handle-customer-account-in-wishlist-layout)