# How to change <update handle="customer_account"/> in wishlist layout

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have override Wishlist layout file in the frontend theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Custom/default/Magento_Wishlist/layout/wishlist_index_index.xml
```

And made below change to update the layout handle.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default"/>
</page>
```

But it's not working and still rendering the customer_account layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento will merge all layout XML files, which is why the Wishlist page still updates the `customer_account` handle.

There are 2 solutions to remove the `customer_account` handle from the `wishlist_index_index.xml` layout file of the `Magento_Wishlist` module:

1. Remove all content within the `customer_account` layout, including blocks, containers, the `class` attribute, changing the title, etc. by using `referenceBlock`, `referenceContainer`, etc. in your layout XML file.
2. Remove the `customer_account` handle directly in the `wishlist_index_index.xml` layout file using the Composer patches plugin.

Because there are many `customer_account` layout files (customer_account.xml) in several modules, solution 1 is difficult to implement and maintain. Therefore, solution 2 is recommended.

For instructions on how to create a custom composer patch, refer to the topic [How to create a Magento 2 Patch?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256571/create-magento-2-patch)

To apply a custom composer patch, I recommend using the [Vaimo Composer Patches plugin](https://github.com/vaimo/composer-patches).
You also can use the [Cweagans Composer Patches plugin](https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches)

There is a Magento official document on how to apply a custom composer patch: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html